# Modificar un href dinamicamente con jquey

Tags: jquery

deseo que en la columna nombre me pueda diereccionar de ese usuario pero al parecer algo estoy haciendo mal ya que el href no reconoce el 
 +respuesta[i].idclient  talves este concatenando mal alguna sugerencia para solucionar este problema

```
 function obtener_productos_exitoso(respuesta) {
    reserva_productos = respuesta;
    $("#tblProductos tbody tr").remove();
    if (respuesta.length == 0) {
        var tabla = document.getElementById("tblProductos").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        var fila = tabla.insertRow(tabla.rows.length);
        var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
        celda1.colSpan = '10';
        celda1.style.textAlign = "center";
        celda1.innerHTML = 'Sin datos para mostrar';
    } else {
        var tabla = document.getElementById("tblProductos").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {

            var fila = tabla.insertRow(tabla.rows.length);
            //fila.style.height = "10px";
            var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
            var celda2 = fila.insertCell(1);
            var celda3 = fila.insertCell(2);
            var celda4 = fila.insertCell(3);
            var celda5 = fila.insertCell(4);
            var celda6 = fila.insertCell(5);

            celda1.innerHTML = respuesta[i].fecha;
            celda2.innerHTML = "<a href='https://www.biz-manager.com/sitio/busqueda_contacto/'+respuesta[i].idclient>"+respuesta[i].nombre+"</a>";
            celda3.innerHTML = respuesta[i].empresa;
            celda4.innerHTML = respuesta[i].name_vendedor;
            celda5.innerHTML = respuesta[i].name_potencial;
            celda6.innerHTML = respuesta[i].nombre_cam;

        }
        get_prospecto_amount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta con esta concatenación

```
   celda2.innerHTML = "<a href='https://www.biz-manager.com/sitio/busqueda_contacto/"+respuesta[i].idclient+"'>"+respuesta[i].nombre+"</a>";
```

Comment: no funciono hermano no reconoce el respuesta[i].idclient  pero gracias por responder

Comment: reconoce la url pero no concatena el idclient

Comment: una pregunta, el respuesta[i].idclient ¿te lo reconoce en otra parte?, me refiero puedes obtener ese dato y mostrarlo en pantalla?

Comment: si lo reconoce ya que si simplemento respuesta[i].nombre.link("link"+respuesta[i].idclient)  funciona a la perfeccion

Comment: perdón yo me habia equivocado en la concatenación ya lo modifiqué por si lo nesesitas probar con esa sintaxis, saludos

Comment: lo acabo de probar y funciona a la perfección gracias

Answer (score 0):

bueno creo que ya encontré una solcion no se si sea la mejor pero funciona
lo que ise fue cambiar la etiqueta "a" por un .link() que si me deja concatenar y eso fue todo

```
function obtener_productos_exitoso(respuesta) {
    reserva_productos = respuesta;
    $("#tblProductos tbody tr").remove();
    if (respuesta.length == 0) {
        var tabla = document.getElementById("tblProductos").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        var fila = tabla.insertRow(tabla.rows.length);
        var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
        celda1.colSpan = '10';
        celda1.style.textAlign = "center";
        celda1.innerHTML = 'Sin datos para mostrar';
    } else {
        var tabla = document.getElementById("tblProductos").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
        for (var i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {

            var fila = tabla.insertRow(tabla.rows.length);
            //fila.style.height = "10px";
            var celda1 = fila.insertCell(0);
            var celda2 = fila.insertCell(1);
            var celda3 = fila.insertCell(2);
            var celda4 = fila.insertCell(3);
            var celda5 = fila.insertCell(4);
            var celda6 = fila.insertCell(5);

            celda1.innerHTML = respuesta[i].fecha;
            celda2.innerHTML = respuesta[i].nombre.link("https://www.biz-manager.com/sitio/busqueda_contacto/"+respuesta[i].idclient);
            celda3.innerHTML = respuesta[i].empresa;
            celda4.innerHTML = respuesta[i].name_vendedor;
            celda5.innerHTML = respuesta[i].name_potencial;
            celda6.innerHTML = respuesta[i].nombre_cam;

        }
        get_prospecto_amount();
    }
}
```